# Extracting information from binary file

Tags: data-recovery, binary

I try to save contents of my phone activity on my computer (messages and contacts).
My phone is a Nokia,the app creating the messages is the basic app embeded in the phone "messaging".

I have loaded a SD card with my messages and contacts, transferred that into my computer, extracted the folders.
Now the issue is, there are many files (1 per message exchanged ?!) in the various folders, and their extension is :
Binary (application/octet-stream)
Therefore I can't read, sort, get my data back. 
I'm pretty new to Linux and this is my first question on this forum, thanks for your understanding of my lack of experience (and lack of correct vocabulary ?!)

I have tried 'file', 'hexedit'... but I am not trying to edit the files, but to transform them into a readable format, and mostly to 'pack', to have all that data in a single document... Just like on my phone my contact list is there clearly, I would like to have the same result available on my computer... Do you see any way to do that ?

```
file 00001CB8491ABE990000201000500000000000000000000000000000000000000+3366566083600000052V0003
00001CB8491ABE990000201000500000000000000000000000000000000000000+3366566083600000052V0003: data
```

```
strings 00001CB8491ABE990000201000500000000000000000000000000000000000000+3366566083600000052V0003 
+33695***646
```

I can read the file using hexedit (I have access to what's inside, but in a very difficult way to read...), therefore I don't think it is encrypted. (or is it?) The phone can't connect to internet and download apps; when I try with a usb cable I don't have access to Contacts and Messages (only to images, audio I believe)

Gratitude in advance for any information ;-)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, encrypted files are almost impossible to decrypt without passphrase. If it is your smartphone, send/transfer all of them by plain text. The mailbox and address book are normally encrypted.

Comment: What kind of phone and what app created the messages?